# Smooth AutoScrolling to Bottom of UITableView and reusable issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to scroll UITableView smoothly with UIView.Animation. I have different speeds. When I set fast scrolling, cells are starting to disappear before they are out of the screen. I think the issue is; UITableView decides cell's job is done, but that makes my requirement unreachable.

The code I implemented for scrolling UITableView is;

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(remainder), delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction , animations: {
            
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(self.currentPoint, animated: false)

        } , completion: { _ in
            
        })
```

I have tried layoutIfNeeded both for self.view and self.tableView, but no success.

Could you please indicate me how to solve it?

BR,

Erdem